# LINQ to SQL - No Add method available

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, insert

I have created a LINQ to SQL datacontext with a single datatable in it.  I am trying to simply insert a new record into that table.  The problem I am coming across is LINQ is not offering an Add method to pass in the new record to.  I have seen countless examples where there is an Add method, but I can't seem to get it.  Am I completely missing something or is it something else?

```
using (praetoriaTestDataContext db = new praetoriaTestDataContext())
{
    PageHit hit = new PageHit();
    hit.DateViewed = DateTime.Now;
    hit.Page = "test";

    db.PageHits.Add(hit); //Add method is not available!
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Table's Add and Remove methods have been renamed to InsertOnSubmit and DeleteOnSubmit.

```
db.PageHits.InsertOnSubmit(hit);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I am going to pick you b/c you added the Remove/DeleteOnSubmit info too.

Answer (score 5):

With LINQ-to-SQL, you want `PageHits.`[`InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but InsertOnSubmit was not appearing either. It turned out that I was missing a reference to the System.Data.LINQ Assembly.