# Why isn't the new row being added to my database table?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var record = new AutorizedActivity();
    record.MbrId = (int) ddlMember.SelectedValue;
    record.ActId = (int) ddlActivity.SelectedValue;

    dbContext.AutorizedActivities.InsertOnSubmit(record);
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Basically, the form has two dropdownlists.  The user makes a selection from each list and presses the button to update a table with their selections.

The problem is, no data is ever being added to the table.  No errors occur at all.  I've stepped through in debug, and can't see anything wrong.  Are there any common things I could check to determine why the program appears to insert a record, but nothing is actually inserted?

Here's my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AutorizedActivities] (
[Id]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[MbrId] INT NOT NULL,
[ActId] INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AutorizedActivities] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_AutorizedActivities_AvailableActivities] FOREIGN KEY ([ActId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AvailableActivities] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_AutorizedActivities_Members] FOREIGN KEY ([MbrId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Members] ([Id]));
```

Here's the datacontext layout, for clarity:
[image]

SOLUTION: The database table **was** being updated... just not the one I was looking at. I was running the program in debug mode, which places a copy of the .mdf in the debug/bin directory. I wasn't looking at that table; I was looking at the table in my production directory. If I had ran the program in release mode, it would have worked like a charm and updated the *live* table, as opposed to the *test* (debug) version.

Comment: No Exceptions No Errors - Are you connecting to the right database ? May be you have development / production database with same structure

Comment: @Habib Hey, Habib!  I checked my connection string and I am, indeed, pointing to the correct database.  Also, the two dropdownlists that the user selects from are being populated with data from two other tables in the database, so I'm pretty sure it's connecting to the right database.  This is a weird one.  I just can't think of what to check next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database table **was** being updated... just not the one I was looking at.  I was running the program in debug mode, which places a copy of the .mdf in the debug/bin directory.  I wasn't looking at that table; I was looking at the table in my production directory.  If I had ran the program in release mode, it would have worked like a charm and updated the *live* table, as opposed to the *test* (debug) version.

Answer (score 0):

Two things might help here, but it's impossible to give a definite answer on this one - you're gonna have to try things. The first things I would try here are changing to the 'standard' structure for EF code, which will "Close/Dispose" the context, and making sure your identity property is set correctly on the Entity itself. Sometimes VS doesn't do that automatically. So, check that setting and change the code to this...

```
using (var dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {
    var record = new AutorizedActivity();
    record.MbrId = (int) ddlMember.SelectedValue;
    record.ActId = (int) ddlActivity.SelectedValue;

    dbContext.AutorizedActivities.Add(record);
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Also... did you misspell "Authorized" - fix that now before it's too late and you propogate that through the whole app.

Comment: Yep, I caught that misspelling just now.  I've fixed it and rebuilt the dbml.  Let me try your suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the `using` directive yields the same result: nothing inserted.  Ah, well.  This is just a small program I threw together to test something.  I may just forget about it, although I hate not knowing what the problem is.  But, in the grand scheme of things, it isn't that important right now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: And, you're checking the DB after the block of code exits? This is an interesting question, but I feel like I'm missing some info somewhere. And, you checked the identity property on the Entity itself, right?

Comment: Check my edits... try using the Add() method instead. Let me know if that works. I think your entity was "detached" - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: You may have hit on something, I'm not sure.  But, I do not have the Add() method on the entity.  When I try to use Add instead of InsertOnSubmit, Intellisense complains.  Could this be an indication of a problem?

Comment: Hmph.  According to this SO post, Add has been renamed to InsertOnSubmit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752191/linq-to-sql-no-add-method-available

Comment: I know what the problem is.  The table I'm using is a local .mdf file.  When I run it in debug, it's updating a copy of that .mdf file in the Debug/Bin directory.  I wasn't looking at that one.  I was looking at the table in the 'production' directory.  Ack!

Comment: OMG... glad you found the issue! I don't know if I would have ever found something like that :)

Comment: Yeah, it was driving me nuts.  I never even thought about the fact that I was running the program in debug and that debug mode makes a copy of the file to write to.  Heh, now I know!  Thanks for your help!